# C# COM DLL with Office 2010 64 bit

Tags: c#, com, ms-office

I may be reposting but I cannot find solution of this.

I create a C# Comvisible Class. This is the following class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace COMTrial
{

    [Guid("2B71BC1B-16F5-4A0D-A015-CAE658A10B07")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    public interface IMyExample
    {
        string GetData();
    }

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual), ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IMyExample))]
    [Guid("2B71BC1B-16F5-4A0D-A015-CAE658A01B07")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Class1
    {

        public Class1()
        {
        }
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public string GetData()
        {
            return "Vikas";
        }
    }
}
```

Then I checked Register for Interop option and even made the complete assembly visible and compile the project and solution.

Then I went to excel and wrote this code:

```
Dim a as Object

set a = CreateObject("COMTrial.Class1")
```

It says,

ActiveX cannot create an object.

The only reason I think of is that I am running Office 2010 64 bit with Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: This link may provide some information: http://officepreview.microsoft.com/en-us/support/choose-the-32-bit-or-64-bit-version-of-office-HA102840825.aspx

Comment: are you `writing C# code or VB.NET Code or a mixture..?` and if it's a Mixture.. where is your `using Microsoft.VisualBasic` line in the header section...?

Comment: not really. I believe what I am lacking is the understanding of registering a DLL in 64 bit environment. Even the articles on the web is not having any detailed explanation.

Comment: @ Kraze, I am using purely C#. And trying to call the function from Excel

Comment: Ok, whoever downvoted my question, please note that this exact piece of code works fine with Office 2007 32 bit, and not working in 64 bit. And for all the sample and explanation available, I am not creating any installer. I am just trying to build the code in a dev machine. Register for COM Interop is supposed to register the component. But it is not. Please help!

Comment: If you addin also 64bit. Basically Office 64bit can only load 64bit dlls

Comment: @parapurarajkumar: Thanks for it. I think that was one of the reason too. Because Visual Studio was creating 32 bit DLL. I had to set my platform to x64 and then I registered it manually to create a 64 bit DLL. I was under impression that Any CPU will create 64 bit dll but I was probably wrong. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then I checked Register for Interop option

That will only register your assembly for 32-bit processes.  Since this is the 64-bit version of Office, you will need to run Regasm.exe by hand.  Do so from the Visual Studio Command Prompt, started with "Run as administrator".  Be sure to use the 64-bit version of Regasm.exe, for .NET 4 it is located by default in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319.  Note the 64.  Use the /tlb and /codebase options to match the IDE's behavior.

Another improvement is to use the [ProgId] attribute explicitly so you don't have to guess at the name and won't have a problem if the project name is not "COMTrial".

Comment: Damn, Visual Studio only registers for 32 bit DLL, that is so lame of Microsoft. I think you are spot on about the 64 bit DLL. I registered the DLL and exported the TLB with 64 Bit RegASM. It said registered successfully and tlb is created as well. However, it says that Automation Error. FileName is not valid. Then I opened Process Monitor and couldn't find anything and this whole class doesn't really depend on any other DLL as it simply has just one sample function to be called from COM. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Ok. It is resolved. I am not sure if anyone can be so dumb. I was using the codebase keyword at wrong place. The thing which I was really looking for is that why Visual Studio is not registering the DLL even after I am checking the regiter for Com Interop. But bingo, you just answered it. Thanks!